# Why do i get "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" Error in this code?

Tags: python, multiplication

I'm trying to do a currency converter, and I don't know how to fix this.
traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jorge/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/conversor.py", line 11, in <module>
    mult=inp*din
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
>>>
```

Here is the code:

```
#currency converter
inp=float(input('Enter a value'))
din=float(input('Which one do you want to convert:eur/ars/mxn/pen/cop/brl'))

eur=float(0.84)
ars=float(97.94)
mxn=float(19.90)
pen=float(4.10)
cop=float(3.800)
brl=float(5.17)
mult=inp*din
print(mult, din)
```

Comment: Why do you need `eur=float(0.84)` when you can directly write it as `eur = 0.84`

Comment: You're not showing your full code. `sequence` means a list or tuple-like type, which can be multiplied by an integer which then effectively copies all the elements `N` times and grows it by that factor. You're trying to multiply a list or similar by a float, which makes no sense.

Comment: What I'm assuming is you're not actually doing `float(input('Wich one do you want to convert:eur/ars/mxn/pen/cop/brl'))`, because that makes no sense, in what case you're trying to multiply a string by a float, which again, makes no sense.

Comment: It doesn't make sense if you are trying to convert strings to float in line `din=float(input('Wich one do you want to convert:eur/ars/mxn/pen/cop/brl'))`

Comment: that line was also confusing to me. I understand based on an answer that the input is supposed to be a string like ‘eur’, but the `float` there is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only giving this answer because the other, provided answer is dangerous, the wrong way to go about things, is not even the ideal way of solving the problem, and teaches awful habits that are hard to unlearn later. There's a great article on why [eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), and it has other drawbacks here too.

The correct way to do this is to first create a dict, a lookup table, of our currency names to our values:

```py
currencies = {
    'eur': 0.84,
    'ars': 97.94,
    'mxn': 19.90,
    'pen': 4.10,
    'cop': 3.800,
    'brl': 5.17,
}
```

This allows us to lookup the value of a currency by providing the name, as `currencies['eur']` will give us the value. Note that we don't have to use `float(0.84)`, because `0.84` is already a float.

Next, we need to get our user input:

```py
inp = float(input('Enter a value'))
din = input('Wich one do you want to convert:eur/ars/mxn/pen/cop/brl')
```

Note that we don't convert `din` to a float, because it's a unit, so we'll look it up in `currencies` later.

Finally, we convert our value and print it:

```py
mult = inp * currencies[din]
print(mult, din)
```

And now your code should work.

Now, why not eval? Well, even if the code provided is safe, you might get:

```py
>>> eval('usdollar')
NameError: name 'usdollar' is not defined
```

Congratulations, you've provided a terrible error when the dict solution works well:

```py
>>> currencies['mydollar']
----> 1 currencies['mydollar']
KeyError: 'mydollar'
```

This is very clear about what the issue is.